# In Safari on macOS, a numbered list beginning with a displayed equation swallows the number

Tags: bug, mathjax, markdown

This bug report did not originally mention the platform and the renderer.  I originally put them at the end, but it occurs to me that they're more useful up front.  Thanks to [@DavidRoberts](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5583/a-numbered-list-beginning-with-a-displayed-equation-swallows-the-number#comment28295_5583) and [@GeraldEdgar](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5583/in-safari-on-macos-a-numbered-list-beginning-with-a-displayed-equation-swallows#comment28299_5583) for reminding me.

This is in Safari 16.3 on macOS 13.2, using any renderer.  The behaviour I am describing seems to be very much a Heisenbug; the more I test it, the more erratically it behaves.  Refreshing a page repeatedly, without changing anything else, will often cause the bug to appear and disappear.  Sometimes the number will show while the page is loading, but then disappear while the load is complete.  The preview while editing is also often different from the rendered result.

```
1. $$1 + 1 = 2.$$
```

produces

1. $$1 + 1 = 2.$$

For me, that usually looks like this:

[image: Numbered list's number is swallowed]

Notice that the number was swallowed.  I would have expected it to behave like

```
 1.
 $$1 + 1 = 2.$$
```

1. 

$$1 + 1 = 2.$$

(For me, the latter always shows the number and the displayed equation on separate lines, which is what I think most TeX users would expect.  As @DavidRoberts [mentions](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5583/in-safari-on-macos-a-numbered-list-beginning-with-a-displayed-equation-swallows#comment28295_5583), this different behaviour does not occur on Firefox.  As [I](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5583/in-safari-on-macos-a-numbered-list-beginning-with-a-displayed-equation-swallows#comment28296_5583) and @AsafKaragila [mentioned](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5583/in-safari-on-macos-a-numbered-list-beginning-with-a-displayed-equation-swallows#comment28298_5583), Chrome seems to behave differently, putting the first equation on the same line as the number.  I think a TeX user would not expect this, but it is not an unreasonable implementation, so I do not complain.)

Comment: They look the same to me with current Firefox on Mac.

Comment: @DavidRoberts, [thanks](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5583/a-numbered-list-beginning-with-a-displayed-equation-swallows-the-number#comment28295_5583)!  I agree, I cannot reproduce the behaviour under Firefox.  (On Chrome, it seems that the behaviour is a 3rd possibility: the number and the equation appear on the *same* line.)  In fact, bizarrely, even on Safari, when I clicked through to see your comment, the number displayed (what I would call) properly, but then it disappeared on refresh.

Comment: Using Chromium on Linux, the first one shows `1.` but no line break; the second shows `1.` and a line break.

Comment: They look the same to me.  Safari 14.1.2; renderer HTML-CSS (With other renderers, I can see differences: both the missing newline and the missing number)... Perhaps the OP (and the other commenters) should mention which renderer.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar, [thanks](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5583/in-safari-on-macos-a-numbered-list-beginning-with-a-displayed-equation-swallows#comment28299_5583)!  I am seeing this behaviour with HTML-CSS and Preview HTML, but only *most* of the time.  Sometimes the HTML-CSS renderer (which is my default) shows the number in the first list; but then, when I refresh, the number goes away.  Does that behaviour happen for you, or does the number remain even on refresh?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar, [correction](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5583/in-safari-on-macos-a-numbered-list-beginning-with-a-displayed-equation-swallows#comment28299_5583):  on *all* renderers, I am seeing the number sometimes load, but go away on refresh.  Using Plain Source, bizarrely, it sometimes starts on the same line, and then refreshing sometimes gets rid of the number and sometimes puts it on a different line.  In some renderers, e.g., MathML and Plain Source, when I refresh, the number will show briefly, but then disappear.

Comment: Playing around with this, I think I can at least describe its reproduction conditions in my browser (Safari 16.2):  On page load/refresh, the list number appears momentarily but vanishes as rendering is completed, UNLESS the already-selected renderer is “preview HTML”, in which case the number remains visible.  On switching renderer (using the contextual menu), the content gets re-rendered, but the number visibility doesn’t change, EXCEPT when switching to “Common HTML” or “MathML” (from any other renderer), which makes the list number appear (and remain visible until a page refresh).

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine, [thanks](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5583/in-safari-on-macos-a-numbered-list-beginning-with-a-displayed-equation-swallows#comment28351_5583)!  Is the behaviour completely reproducible for you?  For me, even with nothing else (including the renderer) changes, I will often see one behaviour (the number visible as expected) on first page load after a while—maybe after the cached version has expired?—and then the other version if I immediately refresh.

Comment: @LSpice: Ah, I hadn’t tried waiting a while like you suggest.  My earlier tests where at my office computer; now I’m at home on a different machine, with Safari 16.0.  Testing again here, the results seem generally the same as I noted before, but as you suggest, on the first reload after a few minutes’ wait (?c15mins), the number is visible regardless of the selected renderer (at least, with a few different renderers — didn’t try all, since it needs the long wait).